# Spring Cloud Config Server Can't locate PropertySource on startup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

When I start my Spring Cloud Config Server I get the following error.

```
Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/configserver/default/master":Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

However when I hit that URL in my browser it exists and the config server is working. What is going on?

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
management:
  context-path: /admin
logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.discovery: 'OFF'
    org.springframework.cloud: 'DEBUG'
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:/home/dev/configs
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
```

Answer (score 14):

If your config server is not intended to be a config client as well you need to set `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` to avoid that log entry (it's harmless though).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question. If that config exists then why do I get the error on startup? I would like the config server to also be also a client.

Comment: You mean you want it to load its own properties from its repository? Try `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true`.

Comment: When I put `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` the error goes away but that means it isn't reading from the repository. If I have an application.yml and configserver.yml in the repository can the config server read from the repository and use the values on startup if it is the only config server? Sorry I haven't been real clear on what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Did you try `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true` or not?

Comment: Yes. I tried `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true` in bootstrap.yml and the error persisted.

Comment: `Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/configserver/default/master":Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: That's expected (as I said above). You can switch it off with `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false`. I feel like I didn't understand yet what you wanted to do.

Comment: Let me see if giving an example would help clarify what I am trying to do. Currently in my config server project application.yml file I have security.user.password=blah. I would like to put this in the application.yml file in the repository and have the config server read from that on startup. This way I could change the password by simply checking in a new yml file into git.

Comment: That's what the bootstrap property is for. Of course, just committing a change in git doesn't change the security of your config server (that would need a restart by default).

Comment: Correct. I would also restart the server for the password change to take effect. So how can I get the config server to bootstrap from a config in the repo?

Comment: By setting `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true` (in `bootstrap.yml`).

Comment: That worked Dave. I thought I tried this before but I may done something incorrect. Thanks for sticking with me in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This error is shown when one of your services is not able to connect to the cloud-config server.
In order to make it work. I assume you are using STS or any Eclipse environment, run your cloud-config server application and then run the other service whose configurations are stored at the cloud-config. It is very important to keep running both the services.
Other precautions that need to be taken care of are: your application's application.properties file should be renamed to bootstrap.properties'
and port should not be used by any other services

Answer (score 0):

**One of the cases is that:** the config server is not able to pull configurations from git repository.

Check git credential:

**May be an invalid git credential.**

OR

**May be the git user has not have proper permission (Guest account)**

[image]

Answer (score -6):

The eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone  and spring.cloud.config.*  configuration in the bootstrap yml file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add your code to the post, instead of images ?