# Spring boot Could not locate PropertySource: label not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying set Spring Cloud Config Server, but  the service config server, it the running on port 8888 which is correct, and another service should run on port 18060, but for reason when I startup, it allocate port 8080 for me and the return a warning "Could not locate PropertySource: label not found", what should I do? Thank you !!!

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375416/spring-cloud-config-server-cant-locate-propertysource-on-startup) it may help

Comment: tried it, but still not working

Comment: @JosephT . Were you able to solve this ? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I had same issue.  Turned out that the config server was not configured yet with a repository.  After filling out the default configuration and restaging, the app listed the labels and loaded the property files.

Answer (score 7):

Add ***@EnableConfigServer*** at configuration class level or main class of spring boot application  and restart the service .it will work .

Comment: Omg I can't believe I forgot this... Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was because I had to set the default branch of my github URI (the branch of the repository set for spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri) in the config server by setting the following to the application.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. I had the same issue and solved.

First enable debug mode in your app.(In your property file: logging.level.=DEBUG . This is only to make sure the issue is same as mine Or you may have any clue of where it can go wrong.) 
Then start the application and see the logs. The log shows the configured server URI and what the **URL** to get all property resources.
Compare both URL s - the one in the log and your Configuration server URI.
Issue is that mistakenly the URL defined the property file can have empty space at the end. (This can happen when you copy past from somewhere ) Example:
the value for spring.cloud.config.uri=http:localhost:< port >***< additional empty space >***

If this is the case, the client's log shows localhost:/*20%20%/* < app name > / < profile >

Simply remove the post empty space. Then it should work !

Answer (score 3):

I ran into similar issue, when I run my server locally I see in the logs only on the stratup

```
o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Could not locate PropertySource: label not found
```

It turned out this is a problem with the health check for the config server, when health check is triggered to config server an empty environment is used so the application name is empty hence the spring cloud client will try to access {config-server}/application since application is the default application name, see [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/386) for more info on this.

To solve the issue I just disabled the health check for config server

```
health.config.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap.yml file
Add these lines

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8888 ##this is the link to the server config
      label: main ##this is what you are missing (name of the git repo branch)
  application:
    name: currency-spring-cloud-config-client
  profiles:
    active: testing


server:
  port: 8600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri:
        - http://localhost:9196   ### your port for cloud config server
      label: main                 ### your git repo branch name
```

Comment: This assumes you are doing config first not discovery first with your config server

Answer (score 0):

In my case my server was fetching cofnigs from github repository, and I forgot that I made it private :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is due to typo in url.
In my case it was due to wrong url typing:

spring:

application:

```
name: employee-service
```

config:

```
import: "optional:configserver:http:/localhost:8088" < Wrong_url>
```

> > > > Not able to connect the config-server <<<<<<

=========================================================================

spring:

application:

```
name: employee-service
```

config:
import: "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8088" <right_url>

> > > So, able to connect the config-server. <<<<<<

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from application.properties file , I just compared properties file with working branch then push changes again and it worked again.